# 7MHz Transducer Measuring Doppler Shift

Tags: ultrasound, transducer, piezoelectricity

I am currently messing around with a project I thought would be fun but am having some issues.

My goal is to use a signal generator to send a wave through my 7MHz (Steminc) piezo s-configuration transducer (through the carotid artery) and to use another transducer to capture the scattered wave and measure the doppler shift. I am trying to do a proof of concept first, and want to just get the measurement through a scope; however, when I try placing them, I only get noise.

My electronics background in theory is ok, but in practice is not strong at all. I'm assuming I need some circuitry or have overlooked something along those lines. I was hoping someone could give me some guidance, whether it be a useful resource or somewhere to start as far as the circuitry.

Comment: We could sure use a schematic or diagram of some type. We need to see what you are doing. You may need an amplifier specific to the transducer your using.

Comment: Are you trying to do this in air?  If so, it is likely that the transducers need to be in a liquid for better coupling efficiency.

Comment: Signal from a signal generator is most probably ways too low to effectively drive transmitting transducer.... usually a few 10 Vpp is needed, can your generator reach ?

Comment: @Barry It is through skin, I am using the hydrogel that you get from hospitals.

Comment: @Sparky the link for my transducer https://www.steminc.com/PZT/en/piezo-ceramic-transducer-16x025mm-s-7-mhz I'm sure that's not what you're looking for but I don't have much else.

Comment: @carloc I'm driving the transmitting transducer at 10Vpp exactly, what should I expect the amplitude of my receiving wave to look like? exactly the same?

Comment: Be careful of signal generators. Many of them offer 10 volts p-p through a 600 ohm or 50 ohm resistor. Also you *will* need an amplifier for the receiver. Unless you can come up with proper instruments to deal with these issues, including the required focusing horn or pipe (think resonator for a horn speaker), we are starting to drift off-topic with opinion based answers.

Answer (score 0):

Signal level directly from the transducer is probably tens of mV at most, and may be getting lost in the scope noise. Try to reflect or transmit from only a few mm and (if not already doing so) use your scope probe in X1 mode, which reduces the input-referred noise floor by an order of magnitude.

For more serious work you will need an appropriate preamplifier.

Comment: The signal generator is pushing a sine wave at 10Vpp, my transmitter is basically right next to my reciever. These are single element transducers, the issue could be that I am placing the transducers at almost 90 degress... do I need anything to be connected to the receiving transducer as far as amplifiers, etc?

Comment: Any specs on the transducers? Are they coupled through an appropriate medium for their design (reasonably acoustically impedance matched)?

Comment: It may be me but I do not think the site gives much, for example I cannot figure out what voltage the transducers should ideally be driven at (see [link](https://www.steminc.com/PZT/en/piezo-ceramic-transducer-16x025mm-s-7-mhz)). They have a material spec sheet (see [link](http://www.steminc.com/piezo/PZ_property.asp)), for material SM211. They are being coupled with a hydro gel, like one you would get at the doctors. I do not currently have a matching material implemented.